# Reference Object Created at Runtime

Tags: java, object

I have two classes: "Player" and "Armor". "Player" contains generic variables you would expect to find in an RPG game. "Armor" contains generic variables relevant to armor.

In the "armor" class, I have this method:

```
public boolean canEquip() {

    boolean tf = false;

    if (this.wieldLevel <= [NEED CODE HERE]) {

        tf = true;
    } else
        tf = false;

    return tf;
}
```

I'm trying to reference an object that wont be created until the player loads a savefile or creates a new game, at which point the Player object would be created. Is there a way to write this method correctly?

```
if (this.wieldLevel <= Player.getLevel())
//this doesn't seem to work.
```

Comment: You can pass the `Player` as an argument and then check the level of the player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ashwin says,  Player should be a parameter to the canEquip() function.

```
public boolean canEquip (Player player) {
    return (player.getLevel() >= wieldLevel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, you can simplify your entire block of the code to the following with the exact same functionality and behavior:

```
public boolean canEquip() {

    return (this.wieldLevel <= [NEED CODE HERE] ); 
}
```

Your statement that you can't check against player properties here is a little confusing for me.  Why would you be checking to see if a player "canEquip" something if there is no player object available that could equip something?

Comment: The Player object is created when the user creates a new game or loads a save file. Thus, there is no object to compare it to. Regardless, Thomas W already has this shown in his post.